# JMX - Minimum jar files

Tags: jmx

I am trying to connect to the Cameron FIX engine using JMX
I have jmxremote_optional in my classpath but keep getting connection refused.

What other jars do i need?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, it was an issue with my ports

Thanks for viewing the question guys